# How do I read a 2 column csv file and create a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

For example given the following csv

```
ID, type
1 , A
2 , B
3 , C
```

it should generate a dictionary that looks like this

```
{'1':A, '2':B, '3':C}
```

Here's what I have so far, but its's associating the entire column into 1 dictionary

```
import csv

reader = csv.DictReader(open('TIS_annotation.csv'))
result = {}

for row in reader:
    for column, value in row.iteritems():
        result.setdefault(column, []).append(value)
print result
```

Comment: Do you have repeating ID's?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham no i dont thankfully haha

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you iterate over each `row` in `reader`, the `row` variable contains all the information you need to make a new entry to the dictionary. You can simply write

```
for row in reader:
    result[row['ID']] = row[' type']
```

To make the dictionary you want.

Answer (score 8):

It's simpler than you thought:

```
import csv

with open('TIS_annotation.csv') as f:
    next(f)  # Skip the header
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    result = dict(reader)
    print result
```

Output:

```
{'1 ': 'A', '3 ': 'C', '2 ': 'B'}
```

Basically, `reader` yields a series of rows, each has two elements, feed that into `dict` and you have it made.

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer. I just worked though something similar [converting to a Counter.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53642743/25197)

Answer (score 0):

#### Other way is to create a tuple and convert to dictionary the tuples, will work for even for txt files.

```
for row in reader:
    ID = row[0] 
    data_type = row[1]
    myTuples.append(tuple([ID, data_type]))

result = dict(myTuples)
print result
```

#### resuling:

> `{'1 ': ' A', '3 ': ' C', '2 ': ' B', 'ID': ' type'}`
>
> you can skip header or first row on read the data/csv so **'ID': ' type'** will not be in dict.

#### shortest way skip first row and also append positions of the row without creating **ID** and **type** variables:

```
next(f) #for skipping first row in the file
myTuples = [] #store tuples from col1 and col2
for row in reader:
    myTuples.append(tuple([row[0], row[1]])) #append col1 and col 2 to myTuples

result = dict(myTuples)
print result
```

#### resulting:

> {'1 ': ' A', '3 ': ' C', '2 ': ' B'}