# Convert 2-column counter-like csv file to Python collections.Counter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-collections

I have a comma separated (`,`) tab delimited (`\t`), file.

```
68,"phrase"\t
485,"another phrase"\t
43, "phrase 3"\t
```

Is there a simple approach to throw it into a Python `Counter`?

Comment: I mean, there is no built-in method for your text-file specifically, but it should be pretty straightforward to parse...

Comment: Should be trivial to code up, why not try it out?

Comment: I have tried it out and my solution isn't as trivial as I hoped.  I'm thinking maybe someone here has a better attempt.
Also, if you search "convert csv columns to counter" or something similar nothing comes up on Google. I thought I'd put something up that people could find.  I'll post my answer if nothing better shows up.

Comment: That is not really a Counter; it is a list over tuples with a string and an int. Is that what you want? Is the Counter to be dynamic?

Comment: Good point `dawg`. I removed it from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't let this go and stumbled on what I think is the winner.

In testing it was clear that looping through the rows of the `csv.DictReader` was the slowest part; taking about 30 of the 40 seconds.

I switched it to simple `csv.reader` to see what I would get. This resulted in rows of lists. I wrapped this in a `dict` to see if it directly converted.  It did!

Then I could loop through a native dictionary instead of a `csv.DictReader`.

The result... **done with 4 million rows in 3 seconds**!

```
def convert_counter_like_csv_to_counter(file_to_convert):
    with file_to_convert.open(encoding="utf-8") as f:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
        d = dict(csv_reader)
        the_counter = Counter({phrase: int(float(count)) for count, phrase in d.items()})

    return the_counter
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary comprehension, is considered more *pythonic* and [it can be marginally faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542742/why-is-this-loop-faster-than-a-dictionary-comprehension-for-creating-a-dictionar):

```
import csv
from collections import Counter


def convert_counter_like_csv_to_counter(file_to_convert):
    with file_to_convert.open(encoding="utf-8") as f:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter="\t", fieldnames=["count", "title"])
        the_counter = Counter({row["title"]: int(float(row["count"])) for row in csv_reader})
    return the_counter
```

Comment: Interesting... this is consistently about 10% faster. ➕1

Answer (score 0):

Here's my best attempt. It works but isn't the fastest.
<strike>Takes about 1.5 minutes to run on a 4 million line input file.</strike>
Now takes about 40 seconds on a 4 million line input file after the suggestion by Daniel Mesejo.

<sub>***Note***: the `count` value in the csv can be in scientific notation and needs conversion. Hence the `int(float(` casting.</sub>

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

def convert_counter_like_csv_to_counter(file_to_convert):

    the_counter = Counter()
    with file_to_convert.open(encoding="utf-8") as f:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter="\t", fieldnames=["count", "title"])
        for row in csv_reader:
            the_counter[row["title"]] = int(float(row["count"]))

    return the_counter
```

Comment: Why not simply `the_counter[row["title"]] = int(float(row["count"]))`. Also are you willing to use pandas?

Comment: Cool. Updated my answer to reflect your suggestion. That cut the time in half. Thanks! I'd prefer not to use pandas but it can't hurt to have some more answers for people to vote on. 

Comment: Also in the previous comment I miss that you can do `the_counter[row["title"]] = int(row["count"])`. No need for float.

Comment: No, [you have to cast to float first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32861429/25197).

Comment: Are the numbers in scientific notation?